# BINGO Probability: Controlling average game duration

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

I wandered over here from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/990517/jeremy-smith) and my understanding of advanced mathematics is limited, so bear with me...

A standard, BINGO game card has 24 numbers arranged in a 5x5 format. The center of the card has a free space. The numbers range from 1 to 75. Each column has 1/5 of the numbers (1-15, 16-30, etc). Every round results in a single number being called. To win, a player must have 5 numbers in a row, column, or diagonal for a total of 12 possible ways to win.

My understanding is that a single player will on average call bingo in 41.36 rounds. [See Wizard of Odds.](http://wizardofodds.com/games/bingo/probabilities/1/)

1. As the number of players increase, does the average rounds to win decrease?
2. Would proportionally increasing the number range (e.g. 1-85 instead of 1-75) cancel the effect of the increased number of players? If so, how is it related?

GOAL: Given a fixed set of players P and a desired number of rounds R, how large should the set of numbers N be?

Example: For 100 players, how large should the set of numbers be for the game to last, on average, 50 rounds?

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. (1) if each column has a 1/5 of the numbers, do you mean each column has 5 numbers randomly selected from 1 to 75 without repeating any other numbers on the card? Or something else: I wasn't sure about your statement in brackets: 1-15, 16-30, etc. (2) What is the role of the free space in the center? How can there be 12 ways to win with 5 numbers in a row, when the centre row and centre column and 2 diagonals can only contain 4 numbers?

Comment: If the game has 75 numbers total, numbers 1-15 will be in the first column, 16-30 in the second column, etc. E.g. Number 7 can only ever occur in the first column...this is how standard American bingo is setup.

Comment: OK, and what is the role of the free space in the center?

Comment: 12 ways for straight lines bingo...5 columns or 5 rows or both diagonals...12 total.

Comment: Free space counts as a marked spot...so everyone starts out with one spot marked for free.

Comment: All the rules are standard for American bingo...only variation for me here is to increase the total numbers in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but it can not be made arbitrarily small. As the number of players increases, the expected number of turns to finish the game will approach $4$.
2. Yes it would, the average game length can be made arbitrarily long if enough numbers are used for the balls. The exact relationship is probably very complicated.

I've opted for a numerical approach, since the probabilities for BINGO are extremely not obvious. I wrote a Python program which (approximately) answers the question: "How many total numbers do we need to make a game last `Nturns` given that we have `Nplayers` people playing?" Note that the number of numbers needs to be a multiple of $5$, otherwise one column would be biased. Since $50$ turns seems to be a good average length for a game, if we just set $R = 50$, I've found an experimental fit for $1\leq P \leq 100$. See this graph:

[image: Experimental fit]

Note that to answer your example question, the model gives $N \approx 256.5$, so we probably need $255$ numbers. Here is the program if you want to compute some results more accurately; simply change the arguments of `how_many_numbers(Nplayers, Nturns)`.

```
from random import shuffle, sample

# General plan: card represented as 5x5 arrays of ints, with
# filled spaces represented by 0's and called numbers being
# represented by [column number, actual number].
# Bingo is obtained with straight lines (including diagonals)

def generate_card(N): # makes fresh card with N numbers (mod 5)
    N_per_col = N/5 # numbers per column
    card = []
    for x in range(0, 5):
        card.append(sample(range(1 + x*N_per_col, N_per_col + 1 + x*N_per_col), 5))
    card[2][2] = 0 # free space
    return card


def generate_draws(N): # makes randomized list of balls to be drawn 
    # for N numbers/card (mod 5)
    N_per_col = N/5
    draws = []
    for x in range(0, 5):
        for y in range(1 + x*N_per_col, N_per_col + 1 + x*N_per_col):
            draws.append([x, y])
    shuffle(draws)
    return draws


def did_i_win(card, filled): # simulates player checking
    # whether or not they won after adding "filled". Player
    # only checks the row an column of the last number he filled,
    # or the diagonal if necessary.
    for column in range(0, 5):
        if card[filled[0]][column] != 0:
            for row in range(0, 5):
                if card[row][filled[1]] != 0:
                    if filled[0] == filled[1] or filled[0] + filled[1] == 4:
                        for x in range(0, 5):
                            if card[x][x] != 0:
                                    for y in range(0, 5):
                                        if card[y][4 - y] != 0:
                                            return 0
                                    return 1
                        return 1
                    else:
                        return 0
            return 1
    return 1


def update_card(mycard, called): # simulates player
    # updating all their cards with the most
    # recently called number; returns 1 if BINGO
    newcard = mycard
    for row in range(0, 5):
        if newcard[called[0]][row] == called[1]:
            newcard[called[0]][row] = 0
            if did_i_win(newcard, [called[0], row]) == 1:
                return 1
    return newcard


def grid_print(card): # Prints a card out as a grid, only used for debugging
    for x in range(0, 5):
        print card[0][x], card[1][x], card[2][x], card[3][x], card[4][x]


def play_game(Nplayers, Nnumbers): # Simulates the players playing a game,
    # returns the number of turns taken for the game to finish
    hands = [] # all players' hands
    for x in range(0, Nplayers):
        hands.append(generate_card(Nnumbers))
    undrawn = generate_draws(Nnumbers) # balls in wheel
    Nturns = 0
    while True: # while no one has won
        Nturns = Nturns + 1
        card = undrawn.pop(0) # Ball drawn and discarded
        for x in range(0, Nplayers): # Players update their hands
            hands[x] = update_card(hands[x], card)
            if hands[x] == 1: # if a player won
                return Nturns


def Exp_N(Ntrials, Nplayers, Nnumbers): # Runs Ntrials simulations and returns 
    # the expected number of turns until a bingo is reached in a game with 
    # Nplayers players and Nnumbers available for the cards
    turns = 0
    for x in range(0, Ntrials):
        turns = turns + play_game(Nplayers, Nnumbers)
    return float(turns)/Ntrials


def how_many_numbers(Nplayers, Nturns): # Determines how many numbers 
    # are needed for a game with Nplayers to last Nturns
    N = 25
    while True:
        Nturns_N = Exp_N(10, Nplayers, N) # change the 10 to 100 for greater accuracy
        if Nturns_N > Nturns:
            best_N = N
            score = abs(Nturns_N - Nturns)
            for N2 in range(N - 25, N + 25 + 1, 5):
                d = abs(Exp_N(100, Nplayers, N2) - Nturns) # change the 100 to 
                # 1000 for greater accuracy
                if d < score:
                    best_N = N2
                    score = d
            return best_N

        N = N + 5

print how_many_numbers(1, 42)
```

Comment: Running this with Players = 1 and Rounds = 41.36, I would expect the number to be close to 75, even if this is a rough estimate. I got 105. Can you explain why this could be?

Comment: @JeremySmith Yes, there's a deep and elegant reason for that discrepancy: I apparently don't know how to program. I fixed it now though, and it returns $N=75$ fairly consistently for $P = 1$ and $R = 41$ even in "low accuracy" mode.

Comment: A programmatic approach to the equation...now you're speaking my language! I've migrated the concepts into another application and am producing the exact same results. Many thanks @mr!

Comment: @JeremySmith No problem! :)